# Should a polynomial satisfying certain conditions be linear?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

Let $f,h \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ be two polynomials satisfying the following conditions:

**(1)** $h$ is separable, namely, $\gcd(h,h')=1$.

**(2)** $f+f'$ is a multiple of $h$.

**(3)** $\gcd(f,h)=1$. Moreover, $h'f=1+Ah$, for some $A \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.

**(4)** $\gcd(f',h)=1$. Moreover, $h'f'=-1+Bh$, for some $B \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.

> Should $h$ be linear? I do not think this should be true, although in the few examples I have found, it is.

**Non-example:**
$f=x^3+x^2+x+1$.
$f'=3x^2+2x+1$.
$f+f'=h=x^3+4x^2+3x+2$.
$h'=3x^2+8x+3$.
But $h'f\neq 1+Ah$, since
$h'f=3x^5+11x^4+14x^3+14x^2+11x+3=h(3x^2-x+9)+(-25x^2-14x-15)$.

**Example:**
$f=x^3+x^2-x+1$.
$f'=3x^2+2x-1$.
$f+f'=x^3+4x^2+x$.
$h=x$.
$h'=1$.
All conditions are satisfied, and $h$ is linear.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, try $h = t^2-t$ and $f = -4t^3 + 5t^2 + t - 1$.

If I have calculated this right, then $h$ is separable, $$f+f' = h \cdot (-4t-11),$$ $f$ and $f'$ do not have roots at $0$ or $1$ and so are coprime to $h$, and

$$\begin{align*}
h'f  &= 1 + h \cdot (-8t^2 + 6t + 3), \\
h'f' &= -1 + h \cdot (-24t+8).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Very nice! Are there additional conditions implying that $h$ is linear?

Comment: I doubt it, honestly! Maybe if you constrain $f$ to have low degree.

Comment: Followup. The equations in conditions (3)-(4) actually *imply* $\gcd(f,h) = \gcd(f',h) = 1$ and this, in turn, implies $f+f'$ is a multiple of $h$ (add the two equations together and use the fact that $\gcd(h,h') = 1$).

Regarding the equations, then, the condition $\gcd(h,h') = 1$ implies $h'$ is invertible in $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[t]}{(h)}$, so the equations (3)-(4) can be reformulated as $f = (h')^{-1}$ mod $h$ and $f' = -(h')^{-1}$ mod $h$. Each of these imposes $d = \deg(h)$ linear conditions on $f$. So, I would expect a solution as soon as $\deg(f) \geq 2d-1$ (as in my example).

Comment: Thank you very much. (Truly I was playing mod $h$ and got very similar results. Next time I will write more details, but anyway I am glad to see a confirmation to my thoughts).